# Swift Sprite Kit: Accessing User Data returns nil

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add characteristics such as health to my SKSpriteNodes "monster" using UserData:

```
monster.userData?.setObject(100, forKey: "hp")
```

When the program detects the projectiles hitting the monster, it needs to be able to access the number I set before and change it as well. However, at the moment, when I try to print the object for the key, it always returns nil.

```
print(monster.userData?.objectForKey("hp")
```

By the way, if it is any help, I am setting the object for the key in a function called addMonster() and I am trying to retrieve the object in another function called ProjectileDidCollideWithMonster(), which executes when the two objects collide. Both objects are passed into the function as parameters.

Thank you so much. Stanley

Comment: Is it possible that your `userData` is `nil`, in which case any value that you try to retrieve from it will also be `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to initialize the User Data dictionary first. Add this line before you set any user data:

```
monster.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
```

Comment: I did add that, although I did not include it in the sample code above. I added it right after I added the monster onto the scene. Would this be an incorrect place?